# How to shrink SectionList sections in React Native?

Tags: react-native, collapsable, react-native-sectionlist

Is there any way to be able to shrink a `SectionList` section, when the user taps on the section title? Something like the way that **Reddit comments** work on the mobile app, where the comments shrink and expanding accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the React Native Collapsible package. By using the expanded prop you can handle the expanding and collapsing actions accordingly.
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible-view